# How do I narrow a class's types to only functions accepting no arguments?

Tags: typescript

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=187#code/MYGwhgzhAEByYDsAmYBO0DeBYAUNf0EALgK4BmZAXIUagJYIDm0APtAiSCNALzucgA3LgLQkAewDK4gLYBTIgAsGjABRhqxekwA00AEabaKgJTUAbuLpJMI0QWDiEEcSDkA6EOLUADACQYYAC%20OgH6QT4mwngEQXb4COJKKqpm0JbWtjH20I7Orh5eagDkiclMxVHx0HE4tbhEAJ4ADnLQksZMACJyboxgRG186kbajHqGNGMmvAB86VZI0U2tcEnK3b1y-YO80KlzC9bRDS1tPX0DchAAPAAqZ3oAYgjzfADWco3iZFmiANoAaWgDGgn2%20vwerWqkGgL2gcgAHoNkDAoXIgQBdaAAfmgwOoCDk5jkqEx1EBuCCJxweWIYi2Ozk1Au2yut3gyDQelg6xUrKZb2gxQk0nk5UYxUE0AA9DLoAB3RBEaDJGBEcQI1CocSoIA)

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Nandar {
    stuff: string | null = null;
    doSomething(a: string, b: string): void {
        console.log(`${a},${b}`);
    }
    nothing(): void {
        console.log('nothing');
    }
}
```

I can use this type to extract the class's properties, narrowing the keys to only a given function signature:

```
type Delegates<Type, Fn> = keyof {
    [K in keyof Type
    as Fn extends Type[K] ? K : never]: K
};
```

For example:

```
type StringDelegate = (a: string, b: string) => void;

const delegate: Delegates<Nandar, StringDelegate>; // delegate's only possible value is 'doSomething'
```

If I want to narrow to `Nandar.nothing`'s type, though, I have a problem.

Using similar code:

```
type NothingDelegate = () => void;
const delegate: Delegates<Nandar, NothingDelegate>; // delegate's values can be 'doSomething' or 'nothing'
```

I don't want 'doSomething'; I want 'nothing' only. Basically Typescript takes `() => void` to refer to any function, using any number of arguments and any return type. That's not what I want Typescript to do: I want it to refer to functions using no arguments and returning nothing.

The [handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void) says that

> a void-returning callback type says "I'm not going to look at your
> return value, if one exists"

But I DO want to look at the return value, and ensure that it is `void`. I also want to ensure that the function has no arguments. Is there syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for a function to be assignable to another, it doesn't necessarily need the same arity. If a function's parameter types matches another function's, and the only difference is that the function takes *less* parameters, then it is assignable:

```
type UhOh = (() => void) extends ((a: string, b: string) => void) ? true : false;
//   ^? true
```

Here you can see that a function that takes no arguments is assignable to a function that takes two arguments. To make sure that the function has no arguments, you may use the [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type to check that it has no parameters:

```
type NoArgFns<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? Parameters<T[K]>["length"] extends 0 ? K : never : never
}[keyof T];

type T = NoArgFns<Nandar>;
//   ^? "nothing"
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL5G2W)

Comment: Okay, a few followup questions.

1. `Parameters<T[K]>['length']` seems to me to be saying 'Get the Array of parameters returned to the Typescript typing system from T[K] and return the "length" property.' Do I understand that correctly?

2. The overall algorithm seems to be 'Make an object. The keys will be the keys from T. The values will be the key we retrieved if the key fulfills our check; otherwise the value will be the "never" type.' Then '[keyof T]' says 'grab the keys from what we just did, excluding never as a side effect.' Do I follow you there?

Comment: @JosephZabinski Yes that is all correct.

Comment: This is probably great for most cases, but I just want to point out a caveat with this approach: it gets tricky with overloaded functions/methods: https://tsplay.dev/WK9epN See other answers which cover this topic: [SO search results for `[typescript] infer overload`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+infer+overload)